# White gap under the footer

Tags: html, css

[On my site here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html), the footer is white at the end when the `padding-bottom` isn't enough and wondered if someone could help diagnose.

Here's the footer CSS:

```
#footer {
color:#E0E0E0;
max-width:1280px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:1.45em 2% 0.4em;
}
```

And I'm wondering if the right-nav equal column CSS is affecting it:

```
.right-nav {
float: right;
width: 29.4%;
border-left: 1px solid #Dddddd;
padding-top:2em;
padding-bottom:10040px;
margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
```

Any ideas would be great.

*Update: [this page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/southend/business-directory/index.html) has a huge gap too, which is why I'm wondering if the right-nav has anything to do with it.

Comment: do you clear:both for the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a sticky footer.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

This is the best tutorial I've found on the web. You may have to do some tweaking to your site's structure, though.

What this does is essentially forces the footer to always be at the bottom of the page, no matter what the size of the content. If the content is large enough, it sits at the bottom of the page as it should.

Comment: +1 good suggestion. Ryan's sticky footer solution is great, I used it on many pages already.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you right
then you need to add overflow to your footer

```
#footer
{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this should work. Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmL2u/) of it in action.

```
#footer {
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
}
```